# Problema en código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Este código no me está funcionado. No entra al `if` y debería de entrar y remover la clase, pero no lo hace. ¿Alguien que me diga si ocupo alguna librería o algo así?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button-menu').click(function(){

        if($('#button-menu').attr('class') == 'fa fa-bars'){
            $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars');
        };

    });

});
```

Comment: Eso es JQuery, estas usando dicha libreria? Ademas 'fa fa-bars' corresponde a la libreria FontAwesome.

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor si usas el método `hasClass` para evaluar si tiene o no esas clases, ya que si tiene una tercera clase asignada o un espacio extra la validación dará `false`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button-menu').click(function(){

        if($('#button-menu').hasClass('fa') && $('#button-menu').hasClass('fa-bars')){
            $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars');
        };

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero:
$('#button-menu').attr('class') posiblemente retorne "btn btn-primary" o algo similar, ya que "fa fa-bars" son clases para crear íconos en un elemento

Segundo:
attr('class') devolverá todas las clases del elemento. en todo caso, considero que en la condición if deberías utilizar hasClass() que es un método que permite verificar si un elemento contiene esa clase.

Por lo tanto, tu codígo debería ser algo similar a:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-menu').click(function(){
    if($('#button-menu i').hasClass('fa fa-bars')) {
      $('#button-menu i').removeClass('fa fa-bars');
    };
  });
});
```

ó, como expones en tu código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-menu').click(function(){
    if($('#button-menu').hasClass('fa fa-bars')) {
      $('#button-menu').removeClass('fa fa-bars');
    };
  });
});
```

Quedo atento a tus comentarios.